# Autoboxing - programming concept

Tags: java, autoboxing

```
1. public static void main(String[] args) 
2. {        
3.    Character s=1;
4.    Float f=1;
5. }
```

Both the lines 3 and 4 have a wrapper class and compiler performs `autoboxing` to convert `1` to `Character` but compiler cannot convert the same `1` to `Float`. Why?

Answer (score 4):

Float numbers you need to append '`f`' or '`F`' at end of the number like this `Float f=1f;` or `Float f=1F`;

Comment: This does not answer why int cant be widened to float. While int could be narrowed to char. Try this: Character s = Character.valueOf(1); Float f = Float.valueOf(1);

Answer (score 3):

That is because, by default it would be a `double`. You need to suffix a float number with `F` or `f` to make it a `float`. *Ex:* `Float f = 1f;`

[§JLS 3.10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2):

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d (§4.2.3).